# How can i add slide animation in uitableview

Tags: ios, uitableview, animation

I have three table view.

[image]

1. Left side tableView is CourseTableView
2. Top table table is MonthTableView
3. Center one is DurationTableView.

I already implemented the functionalities if is scroll DurationTableView either left or right direction MonthTableView also scroll with it. same if scroll MonthTableView either left or right direction DurationTableView also scroll with it.

Same way if i scroll DurationTableView either up or down direction CourseTableView scroll with it same vice versa.

Now i have to implemented if i scroll DurationTableView left or right means CourseTableView shrink to smaller size like sliding the view and DurationTableViewSize should get enlarge up to reset of the space.

if i stop the scrolling of DurationTableView then CourseTableView again should come back to previous size.

How can i achieve this, kindly suggest me. if u have any tutorial for this kindly mention here.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Best solution you have download the code from here :-

https://github.com/preetlotey999/Slider-For-iOS.git

For more help you go through this Blog :-

http://preetlotey999.blogspot.in/

This is a Blog for Developers to make it easy for Developing. If you have any query then post it on this Blog.